# Why is `wget` hanging?

Tags: networking, raspbmc

I have raspbmc (Debian) installed on my Raspberry Pi and it seems to not be able to download anything?

`wget` seems to stall yet it can ping!

The same happens for `apt-get`

```
Resolving google.com... 173.194.41.160, 173.194.41.165, 173.194.41.163, ...
Connecting to google.com|173.194.41.160|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection timed out) in headers.
Retrying.

--1970-01-01 00:17:51--  (try: 2)  http://google.com/
Connecting to google.com|173.194.41.160|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection timed out) in headers.
Retrying.

pi@raspbmc:~$ sudo apt-get install curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libcurl3 libssh2-1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  curl libcurl3 libssh2-1
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 578 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1065 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
0% [Waiting for headers]
```

Does anyone know why this is happening/how to fix?

Comment: Please can you post the output from `sudo ifconfig -a`?

Comment: You are not connected to the internet.

Comment: Why was this migrated? This isn't Raspberry Pi specific

Comment: @user606723 It is an unusual issue, so I think perhaps it is specific enough.

Comment: Is there any chance that this was related to a DDoS attack that happened to Raspbmc recently?
http://www.stmlabs.com/2012/06/24/network-issues/

Comment: This isn't raspberry pi specific at all, it's unix/debian specific, i don't think it should have been migrated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your IP configuration might not be correct.
Try `ifconfig -a`and review your configuration.
I came to this assumption because your system time doesn't get set via NTP.

An other possibility is a proxy configuration.
You could see it with `export | grep -i proxy`

Comment: You were correct, shame this isn't on superuser any more! For some reason the static IP wasn't working. Enabling DHCP fixed it!

Answer (score 3):

Run `dmesg` and see if there are any issues at the end of the output.  I had a problem where insufficient power was being supplied to the Pi which caused the network to drop out every few seconds, and this could exhibit similar symptoms to what you are seeing.

Comment: Seconded my me. Power issues are usually the root cause.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is that you have hit a slow `IPv6 DNS` issue on your internet connection, at lot of ISP's have badly broken `IPv6 DNS` setups which result in long timeouts for negative (not found) responses. Just try:

```
wget -4 www.google.it
```

and see if this is any faster. If you have hit this issue and can find out how to turn off `IPv6` in raspbmc I would love to know also. I am currently researching this problem.

Comment: I doubt he has an IPv6 in the UK!